# How to integrate Wirecard Seamless Payment Extension in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, paypal, payment

I am having issues integrating the Wirecard Seamless Checkout (Magento Extension) in enterprise version for a client's website. With demo data, it doesn't seem to call the `SeamlessConfirmAction()` function, even when the same configuration is set for a different client website (Magento Community) and it seems to be working fine in that.

Please let me know on how to debug on this, considering the Magento order doesn't gets set to Processing mode and I am clueless so far that why isn't it calling the `SeamlessConfirmAction()` and then other functions accordingly in demo mode.

Comment: A fuller response: can you outline what debugging you have done so far? I don't think there is enough information here to be able to assist, especially since it doesn't sound like a feature in widespread usage. Are you looking for a debugging approach particular to Magento? Just using file logging in PHP may do the trick - ensure everything is in version control, and then you can roll back to clear any temporary file edits. Are you working on a local copy?

Comment: Yes working on a local copy. Will debug further and will share more details on it